# bibleref: adding multi volume book and sorting properly

Tags: makeindex, bibleref

Working on a book which references a few deuterocanonical/apocryphal books of the bible, most of which are not included in the default bibleref package.

Some of these are multi-part books, in the same vein as Chronicles, Samuel, and Kings.
In particular, I wish to reference the book of Second Esdras.

I've used the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{indextools}

\addbiblebook{IEsdras}{1 Esdras}
\addbiblebook{IIEsdras}{2 Esdras}
\biblerefmap{Genesis}{01}
% rest of OT
\biblerefmap{Chronicles2}{14}
% rest of OT
\biblerefmap{Malachi}{39}
\biblerefmap{Matthew}{40}
% rest of NT
\biblerefmap{Revelation}{66}
\biblerefmap{Esdras1}{67}
\biblerefmap{Esdras2}{68}

\makeindex[title=Scripture,name=scr]
\makeindex[title=General]

\begin{document}
    % other references and text
    \ibibleverse{IIEsdras}(14:41,45)
    % other references and text
    \printindex[scr]
\end{document}
```

However, 2 Esdras gets sorted in just after 2 Chronicles, instead of after both the old and new testament as one would hope/expect. There's probably some edge case with these kind of books that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm no latex expert (especially in the context of anything outside of a *.tex file), I managed to dig around in the source for the bibleref package itself and find that using

```
\addbiblebook{IEsdras}{\BRbooknumberstyle{1}\BRbookof Esdras}
\addbiblebook{IIEsdras}{\BRbooknumberstyle{2}\BRbookof Esdras}
```

produces the desired results. Could be there's some hangup there I may run into later but for now 'it works.'